# Command to Send XButton1 Click

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

How do I create a Dragon Naturally Speaking command that fires an XButton1 click event? I tried to capture the event with the Macro Recorder, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the post
[Mouse clicking commands](https://knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=12&threadid=30877),
Dragon understands the commands of
"mouse click", "mouse double click" and "mouse right click".

A user gave this advice that helped the poster create his own
command:

> In the dropdown menu where you set the command to "Macro", choose
> "Advanced Script", and put in this code
>
> ```
> Sub Main
> ButtonClick
> End Sub
> ```
>
> See
> https://www.nuance.com/products/help/dragon/dragon-for-pc/scriptref/Content/scrptref/buttonclick.htm